# Print data into file using STM32 Nucleo

Tags: c, embedded, printf, stm32, uart

I'm sampling data from a pressure sensor using STM32F401RE. Using this function I can use the printf() to print data on terminal using "Tera Term".

```
int _write(int file, char *data, int len) {
    int bytes_written;
    if ((file != STDOUT_FILENO) && (file != STDERR_FILENO)) {
        errno = EBADF;
        return -1;
    }
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)data, len, 0xFFFFFFFFU);
    return bytes_written;
}
```

I tried to use this code, but it isn't working.

```
outfile = fopen("output.csv", "a");
data = Read_Pressure();
printf("%d,%d\r\n", time, data);
fprintf(outfile, "%d,%d\r\n", time, data);
time++;
fclose(outfile);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the UART setup etc? Have you verified that the UART works at all? Nobody can reproduce the problem with this little info.

Comment: Where is output.csv located?

Comment: Have You attached any filesystem?

Comment: What toolchain, are you using the STM32CubeMX tool?  You nave no filesystem support in your library retargetting code.

Answer (score 1):

Your `_write()` inplementation clearly supports only `stdout` and `stderr` streams and they are hard-linked (not redirectable) to the UART2.

You need a filesystem, media, and appropriate device driver for that media, then you need to implement `_write()` to support file-descriptors other then `STDOUT_FILENO`(1) and `STDOUT_FILENO`(2) which refer to files.